# What are some differences between distributed and de-centralized services?

Tags: distributed, distributed-system

I am unable to come up with fundamental differences between the two.  I could only come up with examples:

- BitTorrent is a distributed p2p system, but ToR is decentralized.
- Web services are decentralized, but I cannot think of a distributed web-service. (Maybe Diaspora?)

Comment: @jnpcl: I wish I could prove it, but no; this just came up as a discussion with a friend of mine.

Answer (score 0):

distributed systems can be in two type .. centralized and decentralized . Centralized Distributed  Systems ,as client-server system and Multitired Application . Decentralized Distributed  Systems not contains server ,such as peer to peer communication .

Answer (score 0):

If architecturally there is a single point of failure within a system, it is not a distributed system. A decentralized system could be a hierarchical structure where there is still a notion of the root of the hierarchy, a point of failure. A traffic round-about is a distributed version of a centralized system where traffic-lights (in traditional sense) is used.